# How to compute final gradients from multiple intermediate gradients in Neural Network manually by TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I want to compute gradient 'dL/dWfe' by combining three intermediate gradients, which are `dL/dSumwiEi`, `dSumwiEi/dEi`, and `dEi/dWfe`. But when I use tf.gradients to retrieve their gradients, I saw their shapes are not compatible. How can I connect these three gradients to do proper gradient descent for the weights in network `Wfe`.
[image]

My code is as follows,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, \
    Dense, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Lambda, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Concatenate, Average, Deconvolution2D, Activation, Add,ZeroPadding2D, Softmax
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from ats.utils.layers import L2Normalize, SampleSoftmax, ResizeImages, \
    TotalReshape, ActivityRegularizer
from ats.core.expectation import expected
#tf.enable_eager_execution()

n_patches = 10
input_frame = tf.constant(value=1, shape=(1, 100, 100, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
input_patches = tf.constant(value=1, shape=(1, n_patches, 100, 100, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
sampled_attention = tf.constant(value=1, shape=(1, n_patches), dtype=tf.float32)
weighted_expectations_whole_image = tf.constant(value=1, shape=(1, 48), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(value=1, shape=(1, 1), dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.variable_scope('Attention'):
    attention_sub1 = Sequential([
        Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
        Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    ], name='Attention_sub1')
    attention = Sequential([
        attention_sub1,
        Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
        SampleSoftmax(squeeze_channels=True, smooth=1e-5)
    ], name='Attention_sub2')

with tf.variable_scope('Weights_predictor'):
    weights_predictor = Sequential([
        attention_sub1,
        Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
        GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ], name='Weights_predictor')

with tf.variable_scope('Feature_extractor'):
    feature = Sequential([
        Conv2D(36, kernel_size=4, activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(48, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        L2Normalize()  # Ensure the attention produces minimal variance estimator (L2 norm close to 1)
    ], name='Feature_extractor')

with tf.variable_scope('Classifier'):
    classifier = Sequential([
        Dense(512, activation="relu"),
        Dropout(rate=0.5),
        Dense(512, activation="relu"),
        Dropout(rate=0.5),
        Dense(2, activation="softmax")
    ], name='Classifier')

feature_model = feature
expectations_model = expected
classifier_model = classifier
attention_map_model = attention
weights_model = weights_predictor

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
    attention_map = attention_map_model(input_frame)
    weights_predicted = weights_model(input_frame)

    patches = tf.squeeze(input_patches, axis=0)

    features = feature_model(patches)
    features = tf.expand_dims(features, axis=0)
    expectation_one_frame = expected(sampled_attention, features, replace=False)
    estimation_for_whole_image = weighted_expectations_whole_image
    prediction = classifier_model(estimation_for_whole_image)

    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(logits=prediction, labels=y)

t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
a_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'Attention' in var.name]
w_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'Weights_predictor' in var.name]
f_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'Feature_extractor' in var.name]
c_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'Classifier' in var.name]


dAi_dW_att = tf.gradients(attention_map, a_vars)
dwi_dWweightsPredictor = tf.gradients(weights_predicted, w_vars)
dSumwiEi_dEi = weights_predicted # newly input value

# After sampling patches
dEi_dWfe = tf.gradients(expectation_one_frame, f_vars)
dEi_dAi = tf.gradients(expectation_one_frame, sampled_attention)
dSumwiEi_wi = expectation_one_frame

# After compute the final predictions
dL_dWclassifier = tf.gradients(loss, c_vars)
dL_dSumwiEi = tf.gradients(loss, estimation_for_whole_image)


# lets do backprop by hand orz
print("dL/dSumwiEi: ", dL_dSumwiEi)
print("dSumwiEi/dEi: ", dSumwiEi_dEi)
print("dEi/dWfe: ", dEi_dWfe)

#print(dEi_dAi)
#dL_dWfe = dL_dSumwiEi[0] * dSumwiEi_dEi * dEi_dAi * dAi_dW_att

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: What does it mean to "connect" gradients to you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I mean I want to compute a final gradient 'dL/dWfe' by 3 intermediate gradients. Thus, I need to compute the multiplication of these 3 intermediate gradients. But when I use 'tf.gradients' to get 3 intermediate gradients, their shapes are not compatible to do multiplication.